# Wrong displayed of file name with underscore in RTL in WPF

Tags: wpf

I am trying to display a file name "123_xyz.wmv" in a TextBlock in WPF I have set the FlowDirection="RightToLeft" the file is displayed  xyz.wmv_123 which is not correct. Please advice.

Comment: Please post your code, explain why you’re doing that, and what you expect to happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Special characters will separate text in a right to left order and that is why you see the filename as such. In order to get around this, you will need to enclose the filename in a `Run` and specify the `FlowDirection` as `LeftToRight`. Basically it would be like this:

```
<TextBlock FlowDirection="RightToLeft">Filename: <Run FlowDirection="LeftToRight">123_xyz.wmv</Run></TextBlock>
```

Take a look at this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa350685%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for further info. Go down to the FlowDocument section.